# Wfs-T Change Polygon Style

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs-t

i use this example for doing my own wfs-T example. . And my code are same under link. My only problem is i don't change polygon default style. it gives error when i use openlayers style map. How can i change polygon style , i want to change color ,opacity,etc of polygon , please help?

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as user stuporglue already mentioned the style is not a specific wfs-t issue, but you can just have a look at a nice website with Information about the Feature-Style and Stylemaps: http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/olstyle.html

For your Vector-/WFS-T-Layer you could use something like that:

```
var defStyle = {
    fillColor: "#ff0000",
    strokeColor: "green",
    strokeOpacity: "0.7",
    strokeWidth: 3,
    cursor: "pointer"
};
var sty = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(defStyle, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);

var sm = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    'default': sty,
    'select': {
        strokeColor: "red",
        fillColor: "green"
    }
});

wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
    styleMap: sm,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        srsName: "EPSG:4326",
        url: "http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wfs",
        featureNS: "http://opengeo.org",
        featureType: "restricted",
        geometryName: "the_geom",
        schema: "http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=og:restricted"
    })
});
```

Here's a working example of mine with a vector-layer-stylemap:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/yxr5wdjo/

Comment: your welcome. if the question is answered please don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Comment: ok i give useful also your post thanx again

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a WFS-T issue, just an OpenLayers issue. WFS-T is just the protocol for creating, editing and deleting features, it doesn't affect how the feature is displayed by OpenLayers.